# Access Fragment Class Method From FragmentActivity Class in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to achieve access Fragment Method from FragmentActivity Class and change some TextView in that Fragment Layout.


My MainActivity extends FragmentActivty (v4) and its layout -> activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

SelectionFragment class Extends Fragment which has updateLoadMembersData() method (v4) and its layout -> selection_fragment.xml
which contains , tags etc.

In MainActivity Class I'm tryin to run this code:

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            SelectionFragment instanceFragment = (SelectionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.selection_fragment);
            instanceFragment.updateLoadMembersData();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved Data Succesfully Added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


    }
```

```
instanceFragment.updateLoadMembersData();
```

This method try to change some textViews editTexts etc i could not run this method.

But I'm getting errors such as ClassCastException i looked some question like that but could not find and reasonable  solution.I'dont have fragment /fragment tags i have only /android.support.v4.view.ViewPager in activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You're not suppose to supply getFragmentById() with a layout file id. You should use the actual id of the fragment as declared in the layout file (i.e. the one specified by the android:id attribute on the fragment in the xml).

Regardless, the right why to access a viewPager's fragment is through it's PageAdapter, not directly through the FragmentManager. It might work using your method but it's not guaranteed and not safe.